# Inseting Data Into two tables using Spring JPA throwing error

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have two tables

1. tbl_user_info
2. tbl_user_auth

I am trying to save data in both the tables sequentially but data is getting stored in first table and throwing me error as below :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-15T11:17:06.540+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
    "path": "/user/register"
}
```

Entity classes are as follows :

1. UserAccount

   ```
   @Entityd
   @Table(name = "tbl_user_info")
   public class UserAccount {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       @Column(name = "id")
       private Integer id;

       @Column(name = "name")
       private String name;

       @Column(name = "email")
       private String email;

       @Column(name = "mobile_number")
       private String mobileNumber;

       @Column(name = "password")
       private String password;

       @Column(name = "token")
       private String token;

       @Column(name = "admin")
       private Integer admin;

       @Column(name = "country_code")
       private String countryCode;

       @Column(name = "serial_number")
       private String serialNumber;

       protected UserAccount() {
       }

       public UserAccount(Integer id, String name, String email, String mobileNumber, String password, String token, Integer admin, String countryCode, String serialNumber) {
           this.id = id;
           this.name = name;
           this.email = email;
           this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
           this.password = password;
           this.token = token;
           this.admin = admin;
           this.countryCode = countryCode;
           this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
       }

       public Integer getId() {
           return id;
       }

       public void setId(Integer id) {
           this.id = id;
       }

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }

       public String getEmail() {
           return email;
       }

       public void setEmail(String email) {
           this.email = email;
       }

       public String getMobileNumber() {
           return mobileNumber;
       }

       public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
           this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
       }

       public String getPassword() {
           return password;
       }

       public void setPassword(String password) {
           this.password = password;
       }

       public String getToken() {
           return token;
       }

       public void setToken(String token) {
           this.token = token;
       }

       public Integer getAdmin() {
           return admin;
       }

       public void setAdmin(Integer admin) {
           this.admin = admin;
       }

       public String getCountryCode() {
           return countryCode;
       }

       public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
           this.countryCode = countryCode;
       }

       public String getSerialNumber() {
           return serialNumber;
       }

       public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
           this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object o) {
           if (this == o) return true;
           if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
           UserAccount that = (UserAccount) o;
           return Objects.equals(id, that.id) &&
                   Objects.equals(name, that.name) &&
                   Objects.equals(email, that.email) &&
                   Objects.equals(mobileNumber, that.mobileNumber) &&
                   Objects.equals(password, that.password) &&
                   Objects.equals(token, that.token) &&
                   Objects.equals(admin, that.admin) &&
                   Objects.equals(countryCode, that.countryCode) &&
                   Objects.equals(serialNumber, that.serialNumber);
       }

       @Override
       public int hashCode() {
           return Objects.hash(id, name, email, mobileNumber, password, token, admin, countryCode);
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "UserAccount{" +
                   "id=" + id +
                   ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                   ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                   ", mobileNumber='" + mobileNumber + '\'' +
                   ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                   ", token='" + token + '\'' +
                   ", admin=" + admin +
                   ", countryCode='" + countryCode + '\'' +
                   ", serialNumber='" + serialNumber + '\'' +
                   '}';
       }
   }
   ```
2. UserAuthInfo

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "tbl_user_auth")
   public class UserAuthInfo implements Serializable {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       @Column(name = "id")
       private Integer id;

       @Column(name = "client_id")
       private String clientId;

       @Column(name = "user_id")
       private Integer userId;

       @Column(name = "code")
       private String code;

       @Column(name = "access_token")
       private String accessToken;

       @Column(name = "refresh_token")
       private String refreshToken;

       @Column(name = "expires_in")
       private Integer expiresIn;

       @Column(name = "modified_datetime")
       private  String  datetime;

       public UserAuthInfo() {
       }

       public UserAuthInfo(Integer id, String clientId, Integer userId, String code, String accessToken, String refreshToken, Integer expiresIn, String datetime) {
           this.id = id;
           this.clientId = clientId;
           this.userId = userId;
           this.code = code;
           this.accessToken = accessToken;
           this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
           this.expiresIn = expiresIn;
           this.datetime = datetime;
       }

       public Integer getId() {
           return id;
       }

       public void setId(Integer id) {
           this.id = id;
       }

       public String getClientId() {
           return clientId;
       }

       public void setClientId(String clientId) {
           this.clientId = clientId;
       }

       public Integer getUserId() {
           return userId;
       }

       public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
           this.userId = userId;
       }

       public String getCode() {
           return code;
       }

       public void setCode(String code) {
           this.code = code;
       }

       public String getAccessToken() {
           return accessToken;
       }

       public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
           this.accessToken = accessToken;
       }

       public String getRefreshToken() {
           return refreshToken;
       }

       public void setRefreshToken(String refreshToken) {
           this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
       }

       public Integer getExpiresIn() {
           return expiresIn;
       }

       public void setExpiresIn(Integer expiresIn) {
           this.expiresIn = expiresIn;
       }

       public String getDatetime() {
           return datetime;
       }

       public void setDatetime(String datetime) {
           this.datetime = datetime;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object o) {
           if (this == o) return true;
           if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
           UserAuthInfo that = (UserAuthInfo) o;
           return Objects.equals(id, that.id) &&
                   Objects.equals(clientId, that.clientId) &&
                   Objects.equals(userId, that.userId) &&
                   Objects.equals(code, that.code) &&
                   Objects.equals(accessToken, that.accessToken) &&
                   Objects.equals(refreshToken, that.refreshToken) &&
                   Objects.equals(expiresIn, that.expiresIn) &&
                   Objects.equals(datetime, that.datetime);
       }

       @Override
       public int hashCode() {
           return Objects.hash(id, clientId, userId, code, accessToken, refreshToken, expiresIn, datetime);
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "UserAuthInfo{" +
                   "id=" + id +
                   ", clientId='" + clientId + '\'' +
                   ", userId=" + userId +
                   ", code='" + code + '\'' +
                   ", accessToken='" + accessToken + '\'' +
                   ", refreshToken='" + refreshToken + '\'' +
                   ", expiresIn=" + expiresIn +
                   ", datetime=" + datetime +
                   '}';
       }
   }
   ```

Controller :

```
@PostMapping("register") // Needed parameter : All except id and token
    public AuthResponse registerUser(@RequestBody UserAccount userAccount) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        if (userAccount == null) throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Request Body can not be null");
        jsonResponse = new JSONResponse();
        if (!userAccountService.isEmailPresent(userAccount.getEmail())){
             userAccount.setPassword(DigestUtils.md5Hex(userAccount.getPassword()));
             return userAccountService.registerUser(userAccount);
        }
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,"Email ID Already Exists");
    }
```

Service :

```
public AuthResponse registerUser(UserAccount userAccount) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        UserAccount ua = userAccountRepository.save(userAccount);
        String token = tokenService.createToken((ua.getId()));
        //Saving the user id and newly created token in tbl_token_info
        ua.setToken(token);
        UserAccount ua1 = userAccountRepository.save(ua);
        UserAuthInfo userAuthInfo = new UserAuthInfo();
        userAuthInfo.setClientId(UtilityMethods.clientId);
        userAuthInfo.setUserId(ua.getId());
        String code = UtilityMethods.getCode(userAccount.getEmail(), userAccount.getPassword());
        userAuthInfo.setCode(code);
        String accessToken = UtilityMethods.getAccessToken(code);
        String refreshToken = UtilityMethods.getRefreshToken(code);
        userAuthInfo.setAccessToken(accessToken);
        userAuthInfo.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
        userAuthInfo.setExpiresIn(3600);
        userAuthInfo = userAuthService.saveUserAuth(userAuthInfo);
        AuthResponse authResponse = new AuthResponse();
        authResponse.setAccessToken(userAuthInfo.getAccessToken());
        authResponse.setRefreshToken(userAuthInfo.getRefreshToken());
        authResponse.setExpiresIn(60);
        authResponse.setCreatedDateTime(UtilityMethods.getCurrentDateTime());
        return authResponse;
    }
```

Please guide what is wrong.

Comment: try debugging or add some log statements to figure out which save-call causes the error

Comment: `ConstraintViolationException` is the reason, can you add complete stacktrace?

Comment: @MarcStröbel I am able to save data in first table ( UserAccount ua1 = userAccountRepository.save(ua);) Till this line.

Comment: @emotionlessbananas Right now I do not have access to stacktrace. I am using postman tp test api .

Comment: @MarcStröbel I can not debug it as the API is online and I am using postman to test API. It looks like it is failing at this line -> userAuthInfo = userAuthService.saveUserAuth(userAuthInfo);

Comment: check the database setup if there are constraints on columns like not null. Difficult to guess without debugging or proper logs

Answer (score 0):

you must use relations between tables:

@OneToMany for 1-N composition relation in tables.
@Embedded for 1-1 relations

@ManyToOne for N-1 association relations in tables.

Don´t use bidirectional relations. Always unidirectional.

if you don´t use this, the mapping of the database could be wrong.